# Python no ejecuta condicional IF y salta directamente a ELSE (básico)

Tags: python-3.x

Hola comunidad estoy haciendo el curso master de python de udemy y me encuentro en el siguiente enunciado:

Ejercicio 2

Crear un programa que permita al usuario elegir un candidato por el cual votar. Las posibilidades son: candidato A por el partido rojo, candidato B por el partido verde, candidato C por el partido azul. Según el candidato elegido (A, B ó C) se le debe imprimir el mensaje “Usted ha votado por el partido [color que corresponda al candidato elegido]”. Si el usuario ingresa una opción que no corresponde a ninguno de los candidatos disponibles, indicar “Opción errónea”.

El problema que me encuentro es que no me ejecuta los IF ni ELIF sino que salta directamente al ELSE, este es mi código (ver imagen)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de hecho si pongo un solo condicional también salta directamente al else, ¿alguien tiene idea de por qué? muchas gracias.

Comment: imprime el tipo de dato que es `candidatoElegido` haciendo `print(type(candidatoElegido))` y dinos cual es el resultado, también prueba quitando esos paréntesis en los que encerraste al `input`

Comment: Por favor, evita usar imágenes para mostrar código. Como habrás notado, alguien tuvo que transcribir tu código para ayudarte, y eso es mucho trabajo para nosotros. Aquí otros motivos por el cual es importante poner el código como texto, [formateado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) como corresponde: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/158880

Answer (score 0):

Como consejo la próxima vez que pongas tu problema pon el código, hasta hay una opción para formatear correctamente el código en la propia pregunta. En cuanto a tu código te recomendaria que revisaras la identación entre if´s y los elifs, porque tal cual el mismo codigo que mencionas lo transcribi y me corrio sin problemas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedes observar abajo le di como entrada "verde" y me lo mostro correcto.
Acá, te anexo también el código formateado:

```
candidatoA = "rojo"
candidatoB = "azul"
candidatoC = "verde"

candidatoElegido = input("Ingresa tu candidato: >")

if candidatoElegido == candidatoA:
    print("Ha elegido el candidato rojo")

elif candidatoElegido == candidatoB:
    print("Ha elegido el candidato azul")

elif candidatoElegido == candidatoC:
    print("Ha elegido el candidato verde")

else:
    print("Elección invalida")
```

¡Saludos!

Comment: nop! no lo has transcrito correctamente, en la línea 4 (imagen de la pregunta) se hace `candidatoElegido = (input("Ingresa tu candidato: >"))` (poniendo paréntesis al resultado de `input`) lo que conlleva que **pueda** ser interpretado como tupla (dependerá de la versión de python e intérprete usado) pues como lo mencionas todo es correcto y no se ve ningún error.

Comment: Tienes razón, ese paréntesis en la entrada del usuario puede ser interpretada como tupla y que de ahí derive el problema...

Comment: @Christian abajo a la izquierda de la imagen dice `Python 3.10.2 64 bits`

Comment: @DanteS. O_o tengo que ir al oculista (creo que si hubiera visto la imagen en una pestaña aparte lo hubiera notado)

Comment: En realidad, analicé la imagen buscando si aparecía, asi que no te preocupes ;)

Comment: Hola, no tengo idea de por qué no funciona alguien más arriba me ha dicho que le ha funcionado, ¿tienes idea de qué pueda estar pasando?

Comment: El resultado con type es str

Comment: Amigos lo tengo solucionado era una tontería :/ gracias por haberme ayudado y acompañarme en este largo pero emocionante camino de aprender a programar